# How to detect error type for Audio tag with Sources

Tags: javascript, html, audio, error-handling

It appears that before the `<source>` element was introduced for `<audio>` tags, when the audio had an error you could see the error code in `audio.error.code`. However, this doesn't seem to happen anymore. Since the error events are now only fired on the child `<source>` elements and no longer on the audio tag, the audio tag no longer has an `error` property (it's always null). The source tags don't get an error property either.

You can see this in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/straker/6qae6qkd/).

How are you suppose to detect the error type now that the audio tag doesn't get an error property? It seems that this is bug in every browser.

Comment: the error events should still fire...

Comment: I see error events on all of your sources (chrome 37.0.2062.120 on mac)

Comment: the error events still fire, thats not my question. My question is how do you see what the error is (no audio found, no internet connection, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

onerror will fire if you add true after the function.

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');    
audio.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    var noSourcesLoaded = (this.networkState===HTMLMediaElement.NETWORK_NO_SOURCE);
    if(noSourcesLoaded) console.log("could not load audio source");
}, true);
```

Comment: Is networkState the only property we have to detecting what type of error was thrown? It seems that it's only good at detecting 404 errors.

Comment: I do not know, I only know the basics of the html5 audio/video stuff. You can always inspect `this` and `HTMLMediaElement` and see what other properties they have.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular you can fire this event to know if aodio did load or not.

```
 this.audio.addEventListener('error', ()=> {
 console.log("could not load audio source");
 ///Do your thing 
 });
```